# Setting the Coolbits in 20.04 without blowing X

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'm trying to set the Coolbits in 20.04 in order to gain manual gpu fan control.

I edited the nvidia the X configuration file `10-nvidia.conf` already present in `/usr/share/X11`:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Note that I just added `Option "Coolbits" "28"`

This didn't have any effect whatsoever.

What is the correct way of setting the coolbits in 20.04, given my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, coolbits option should be in Section "Device" and not Section "OutputClass".

For only manual GPU fan control, you can set coolbits to 4. 28 also works, as it's 16+8+4 (each being a different bit in binary), giving you two more sets of options as well (I think one is overvoltage (16), and the other is to change performance settings per clock (8).

Comment: Whenever I google for these, I never find any official documentation from NVIDIA. Only information scattered across the internet and difficult to put together. Does anyone have a link to official nvidia pages?

Comment: I thought there wasn't any info from Nvidia officially, but the archlinux wiki page has most of the information on this, and I stand corrected:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks

File with official documentation:

/usr/share/doc/nvidia/html/xconfigoptions.html

Or here:

https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/430.14/README/xconfigoptions.html#Coolbits

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:

In `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` add:

```
allowed_users = anybody
needs_root_rights = yes
```

and change permissions:

```
chmod 2644 /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

---

I got this working in a multi GPU config with 470.63.01 drivers. I thought that the problem was with Coolbits, but it actually was the `Xwrapper.config` (by the way, I set the Coolbits in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`).

I'm not sure why the command:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=16 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

breaks your X. For me it worked, and X is behaving normally so far. I'm using the default GNOME and multiple desktops. I cannot assist you with this, however, because it was not the problem. This command added a bunch of lines to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, containing 3 entries for each GPU, that look like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

...

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce xxxxxxx"
    BusID          "PCI:x:0:0"
EndSection

...

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "16"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Even after applying the command, the fan setting won't work unless the `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` file is edited. I had to add the following lines:

```
allowed_users = anybody
needs_root_rights = yes
```

Then save it and change the permissions:

```
chmod 2644 /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

Adding these lines and rebooting did the trick for me. Without them, `nvidia-settings` just fails.
I found this solution [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/unable-to-set-fan-speed-on-the-newest-465-drivers/176816/7).

Comment: I will try this ASAP and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia Driver 470.63.01.

1. In Terminal run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
2. Under `Section "Device"` *add this line*:

   ```bsh
   Option         "Coolbits" "4"
   ```

   It should look something like this:

   [image: Device section in xorg.conf]
3. Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>O</kbd> to write out (save) the file, then press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>x</kbd> to exit `nano` back to Terminal.
4. Then in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
   ```
5. Add `#` to the following line (the `#` means it's just a comment now, not a parameter)

   ```
   # allowed_users=console
   ```
6. Add these two lines:

   ```
   allowed_users = anybody
   needs_root_rights = yes
   ```

   [image: Xwrapper.config edit]
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to write out (save). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit `nano`.
8. Then in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo chmod 2644 /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
   ```
9. Reboot your computer.

Comment: Please don't use screen shots for text as they aren't text searchable.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. It's `Option "Coolbits" "13"`. Also, my conf file is `xorg.conf` at `/ect/x11` (you can generate one with `nvidia-xconfig`). It looks like this:

```bsh
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 455.28

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 435.21

Section "ServerLayout"

    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Microstep MSI G241"
    HorizSync       180.0 - 180.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 144.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"

    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    Option         "Coolbits" "13"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "On"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-4: 1920x1080_144 +0+0 {AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}, HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60 +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Unfortunately if I generate `xorg.conf` with `nvidia-xconfig`, it blows X. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to switch the primary GPU to your NVIDIA-GPU

`sudo prime-select nvidia`

This is telling X to use NVIDIA as your primary GPU

- reboot

2. In /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config add:

`allowed_users = anybody`

`needs_root_rights = yes`

and change the permissions:

`sudo chmod 2644 /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`

3. Now you can enable cool-bits with:
   `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=16 --allow-empty-initial-configuration`

- This will enable cool-bits but the problem that rises is that now only the NVIDIA-GPU is used. This means that only the Monitor that is connected with your NVIDIA-GPU is going to work.

to fix that we first need to get the list of all GPU's in your system
`sudo lshw -C display`

4. Now you need to open `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add your GPU as a device

Section "Device"

```
Identifier     "Device0"

Driver         "modesetting"

VendorName     "Intel Corporation"

BoardName      "Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630"

BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
```

EndSection

Section "Device"

```
Identifier     "Device1"

Driver         "nvidia"

VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"

BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650"

BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
```

EndSection